# How to detect the location of my finger through in a scrollview or webview in Swift? (using touchesMoved if possible)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to print the location of the user's finger on a webview.

Using this (below) doesn't work on a webview

```
 override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: self.view) // even when i replace this part with UIWebview
        print(position.x)
        print(position.y)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that creating a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` should solve it, add the following code into `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // ...

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(webViewtouchMoved(panGesture:)))
    panGesture.delegate = self

    webView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

    // ...
}
```

`webViewtouchMoved(panGesture:)` method:

```
func webViewtouchMoved(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if panGesture.state == .began || panGesture.state == .changed {
        let position = panGesture.location(in: view)
        print(position.x)
        print(position.y)
    }
}
```

also, you should add this `extension` for the desired ViewController:

```
// change 'ViewController' to your class name:
extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

hope this helped.

Comment: oh! that's right, it should be panGesture. I will edit it.