# How can I find out if I have a UIView where I am long pressing as I move the touch point?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, swift3

I am trying to figure out how I can determine if my touchpoint is where I have a UIView as subview or not. The background is UIView itself that I am adding multiple other UIViews to ... So as I long press and am changing the position while holding the touch, I'd like to know if there's a UIView at that point or not.

I have been thinking, still not clear how to go about it but came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758891/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-sub-uiview-in-the-parent-view) which makes me think of getting the indexes of hierarchy and check of it is larger than 1. But how could I do that for where I'm touching?

Any hint or clue would be appreciated.

Comment: Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701494/how-to-detect-the-location-of-my-finger-through-in-a-scrollview-or-webview-in-sw/40701751#40701751) useful to your case?

Comment: nope! Question is how to find if I have multiple layers (subviews) at the location I am touching not to find x and y.

Comment: Are you using touchesBegun method to detect touch or UIGestures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store both reference in two objects `myParentView` and `mySubView` now just use this method..

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView: myParentView];
    UIView* viewYouWishToObtain = [self hitTest:locationPoint withEvent:event];
    if(mySubView == viewYouWishToObtain){

         //That view is touched
    }else{
        //That view is not touched
}
}
```

Comment: I have multiple UIViews and really all I need is to check if there's a UIView where I'm touching as I move that touch point. I think I figured it out last night , the hitTest is an easy way and then I just check of the tags as I know my UIView tags are greater than a number. So as long as the returned view's tag meets the condition I know there's a uiview there. Any way, I think your answer is pretty close so , thumb's up !